onClick event not calling function
I'm writing the following TypeScript class:
"use client"

import { Database } from "@/types/supabase";
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/client";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import { Lora } from "next/font/google";
import { clickPost } from "../action";

const lora = Lora({ weight: "400", subsets: ["latin"] });

interface PostProps {
    type: string;
    video: Database["public"]["Tables"]["videos"]["Row"];
    isActiveSub: boolean;
  }

export const Post = ({type, video, isActiveSub}:PostProps) => {
       
        return (
            <div className="hover:cursor-pointer" onClick={clickPost}>
                <div className="bg-white flex flex-col md:flex-col-2 flex-row rounded-lg max-w-screen md:flex-row-reverse hover:bg-gray-100">
                    
                    {/* Picture */}
                    <div className="">
                        {video.picture_uri && <Image
                            src={"/VideoImages/" + video.picture_uri}
                            alt="Hero"
                            sizes="100vw"
                            className="aspect-video object-cover w-full h-auto rounded-lg"
                            width={500}
                            height={400}
                            /> }
                    </div>

                    {/* Text */}
                    <div className="text-center md:text-left p-4 space-y-4">
                        <div className="text-primary text-sm md:text-md">
                            {video.channel_name}
                        </div>
                        <div className="text-lg md:text-xl">
                            {video.title_1}
                        </div>
                        <div className="hidden md:block text-sm md:text-md">
                            <p className={lora.className}>
                                {queryDescription("big", video.id)}
                                <span className="text-primary"> Leggi di più</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="block md:hidden text-sm md:text-md">
                            <p className={lora.className}>
                                {queryDescription("small", video.id)}
                                <span className="text-primary"> Leggi di più</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}

async function clickPost() {
    console.log("qwert");
    window.location.reload();
}


Everything is working and showing correctly. The only thing that doesn't work is the line <div className="hover:cursor-pointer" onClick={clickPost}>, where the cursor-pointer is correctly shown, but the clickPost function is not called. Am I doing something wrong?
I tried editing the clickPost call by replacing onClick={clickPost} with onClick={() => clickPost()} with no success.
I've also tried moving the function to a different file.

Most likely it's because the div is completely filled by another div, so clicking it is obscured. Could you try moving onClick to it's first child div instead?

Nope, it didn't work

I see. What happens if you place the function on some other visible component? Are you sure that the clickPost function works correctly?

have you already tried replacing clickPost with a locally defined test method: a console.log or whatever?  to see if the issue is with clickPost or with the div onClick event itself.  Hoopra may be right about an obscuring parent div and this would reveal that, too.
